# navigate to a Page from the ContentDialog

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I have a ContentDialog that will be shown when I click on a Button in "MyPage" interface,this ContentDialog contains a button "Connexion" that let me navigate to the "ConnexionNvPage" page
this is my code:

MyPage.xaml.cs:

```
private async void WithoutCnx_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
                await new MyContentDialog().ShowAsync();

        }
```

MyContentDialog.xaml.cs:

```
 private void ConxBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
           //this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(ConnexionNvPage), null);
        }
```

MyContentDialog.xaml:

```
<ContentDialog
    x:Class="Project.MyContentDialog"
    .......
    >
    <Grid>
       <Button Content="Connexion" x:Name="ConxBtn"   Click="ConxBtn_Click"  />
    </Grid>
</MyContentDialog>
```

but I still can't navigate to the "ConnexionNvPage" from the ContentDialog
thanks for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ways you can do this:

Get the Window frame instead of using this.Frame

```
(Window.Current.Content as Frame)?.Navigate(typeof(ConnexionNvPage), null);
```

Or get the ContentDialog result instead of using the click event handler (useful for cases when you simply define the primary/secondary buttons and use those)

```
var result = await new MyContentDialog().ShowAsync();

// primary button was clicked
if (result == ContentDialogResult.Primary)
{
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(ConnexionNvPage), null);
}
```